# Breeze DTO Service -- Metadata query failed for: breeze/DTO/Metadata; An error has occurred -- Error

Tags: iis, breeze

We are using Breeze in our SPA (Durandal), till now we were using EF5 to return the metadata Breeze requires, but now we want to use DTO in certain scenarios, so we have implemented it following http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/ef-design-tool, it works well in development environment but when we deploy it on IIS it returns "Metadata query failed for: breeze/DTO/Metadata; An error has occurred."

I have checked the paths to the service is correct.

Please help....

Comment: What do you mean "*I have checked the paths to the service is correct.*"? What did you do to determine that the request and response are the same to both the development server and your IIS server?

Comment: Just to clarify l have checked that the path for DTO service has the correct virtual directory on IIS, also on further analysis I found that Webdeploy ( which we use for publishing) adds a new connection string to the web.config corresponding to the DTO context

Comment: What I'm looking for you to say is that you have examined the actual URL produced by your app. You'll find it in the network tab in the browser's developer tools. My bet is that the URL in the request is NOT correct when you are trying to reach IIS. Please show us the actual request URL AND confirm whether that URL retrieves metadata or not..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue the  root cause was that an dummy connection string is required for DTO to work especially in the case if Webdeploy is being used to publish the code. I referred the Breeze Sample "DocCode" web config --

```
<!-- TODO: is this needed?
         phony FoosMetadataContext connection enables FoosMetadataProvider to succeed; there is no nonsense.sdf-->
    <add name="FoosMetadataContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|nonsense.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```